Why is Curl licensed under an MIT-like license despite using a GPL library?
Curl is licensed under MIT-like license, but it can use the WolfSSL library, which is licensed under GPLv2. Why doesn't WolfSSL's GPLv2 copyleft "viral" effect cover Curl? Is it because WolfSSL can be replaced with another library (for example, OpenSSL, which uses the Apache License 2.0)?

Curl can be configured to be built to depend on no TLS library or a specific TLS library like OpenSSL (licensed under Apache 2.0), WolfSSL (licensed under GPLv2+) or NSS (licensed under MPL2). This dependency is in the form of dynamic linking.
It does this using conditional compilation.
This means that Curl's dependency on WolfSSL can be conditionally compiled and linked. It doesn't always depend on WolfSSL.
When Curl does depend on WolfSSL, the conditions of the GPLv2 applies to the whole combination of Curl and WolfSSL, which is considered to be a derivative work of WolfSSL. It doesn't apply to Curl alone. Curl is licensed under the MIT license which is compatible with GPLv2.
So, when Curl is conditionally compiled to be dependent on WolfSSL, this combination is subject to the conditions of both MIT and GPLv2 simultaneously, which is possible because both licenses are compatible with each other.
License compatibility here simply means that fulfilling the conditions of both licenses simultaneously does not conflict with the conditions of either license.
When Curl is conditionally compiled to be dependent on OpenSSL but not WolfSSL, then the conditions of MIT apply to Curl and the conditions of Apache 2.0 apply to OpenSSL. GPLv2 doesn't play any role to this combination since there's no linking dependency against WolfSSL or any other GPLv2-licensed library.
Your next question might be "why doesn't dynamic linking of Curl against OpenSSL create a derivative work out of OpenSSL?"
The Apache License v2.0 clearly states:

For the purposes of this License, Derivative Works shall not include
works that remain separable from, or merely link (or bind by name) to
the interfaces of, the Work and Derivative Works thereof.

Also interesting to note is the fact that the GPLv2 license is incompatible with the Apache 2.0 license. But WolfSSL is licensed under GPLv2+. And GPLv3 is compatible with Apache 2.0. So, Curl cannot be conditionally compiled to depend on both OpenSSL and WolfSSL simultaneously and be distributed from a licensing perspective (assuming that it would be technically possible to do so) unless WolfSSL's license is upgraded to GPLv3.

"Curl cannot be conditionally compiled to depend on both OpenSSL and WolfSSL simultaneously from a licensing perspective" Yes, it can: neither compiling nor running something is covered by a copyright license. You wouldn't be able to distribute the combination under GPLv2, but the WolfSSL licensing allows upgrading to GPLv3 which is compatible with the Apache 2.0 license.

Do you want to say that if code that uses GPL-licensed library can be disabled during conditional compilation, the project containing this code can be legally distributed under MIT license, if I build binaries from MIT project with disabled GPL-dependent code, I can distribute it under MIT, but if I build it with GPL-dependent code, I can legally distribute it only under GPL? I mean code that uses GPL library under "GPL-dependent code".

@PhilipKendall I forgot about WolfSSL being upgradeable to GPLv3 which is compatible with Apache2. Also included the point on distribution. Thanks.

@t1m013y If GPL-dependent code is disabled by conditional compilation, it can be distributed under MIT alone. If GPL-dependent code is enabled by conditional compilation, it must be distributed under the terms of both MIT and the GPL.

These comments and the answer could be easier to understand if they clarified when they talk about a binary, or about the source code. The source code files can always be distributed under any license chosen by their author, even if they call GPL functions - the functions are not in the files. With static linking the GPL code is literally combined in the binary, and with dynamic linking things get more murky but the general consensus is that GPL covers the binary that links to the library.

@jpa I'm not at all sure that I agree with that.  GPLv3 s5, covering "modified source distributions" (which is source distribution after combination with other code, the specific case you're quoting above) says pretty clearly in subsection c that the entire work must be licensed under GPL.

@MadHatter I don't see where I quoted such case. Curl source code doesn't include WolfSSL source code. For that matter, when dynamically linked, curl binary doesn't include WolfSSL either, but linking is considered derivative. I haven't seen any claims that the source code file containing a function call would itself be affected by GPL.

The main point is precisely that: curl does not depend on WolfSSL. It depends on a library which implements a specific API, and that dependency can be fulfilled by various implementations. Some of those are GPL licensed (WolfSSL, GnuTLS), some of them are permissively licensed (OpenSSL). If you select a permissive license for the SSL dependency (and any other dependencies), it's perfectly possible and legal to distribute curl under permissive terms.
At this point, it is also perhaps worth digging into the point made in a comment on your previous question: you can combine permissively licensed code with copyleft code, but if you distribute the combination (which includes the binary), you must do so under the copyleft terms. This becomes relevant only if a recipient of the combination wishes to strip out the copyleft dependency. For example:

You build curl with WolfSSL and distribute a copy to me, including the full source for all components as you are required to do.
I wish to reuse curl's HTTP response handling, so take that small part of the source and put it into another program I am writing.

At this point, I can use the source code from curl under the permissive license, even though you distributed it to me under copyleft terms. This is practical in this case because I can draw some clear lines around what is derived from the copyleft code and what is not.

Do you mean that if GPL dependency is unnecessary for working build of MIT-licensed project/library, the project can be licensed under MIT?

The project can always be licensed under MIT, or any other license you choose. If you make the wrong choices, you may create something which it is impossible to legally distribute; you need to be clear on the difference.

I mean legal distribution of project (I think publishing the project to GitHub counts as distribution and it must be legal)

It means I can legally distribute MIT-licensed project that can use GPL library if GPL library is not necessary to build/use project but it can be used for adding some features to the project?

@t1m013y wolfssl's copyright is for wolfssl, and wolfssl's derivative works. When the wolfssl creator gets a lawyer and a court room to sue the curl creator, the judge or jury will decide if curl is a derivative work of wolfssl. curl isn't a derivative work of wolfssl, so it doesn't have to obey wolfssl's license. However, if it was a derivative work, then it would. Nvidia says its Linux driver isn't a derivative work of Linux, and they are right.

So I am free to take curl without SSL, and WolfSSL, and build a combination for myself because their licenses allow it, but I’m not allowed to distribute it because that necessarily violates one of the two licenses. And I can give you curl, and give you WolfSSL, and give you instructions how you can combine them.

@gnasher729 You can distribute curl with WolfSSL because the curl license (effectively MIT) is compatible with the WolfSSL license (GPL v2), just in that case you have to distribute the combination under the GPL v2.

in other words it is possible to find a license you can legally use for the combination, which is GPL v2 PLUS the copyright notice from MIT.
